# How to use <a href> tag in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, href, jtextpane

I have a `JTextPane` which displays a link to which on click should open a page in the browser.

The link is set as a text to the `TextPane` as shown:

```
<a href=http://www.google.com target=_blank>Read more..</a>
```

**Also below shows how the link looks like in my pane:**

[image]

When I click on this nothing happends, do anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the JTextPane should be non-editable as it's stated by BegemoT or you can use this
http://java-sl.com/tip_links_in_editable.html to allow links in editable pane.

Answer (score 3):

You need JTextPane to be non-editable for link to activate, and install HyperlinkListener on it to provide action which should be done when link clicked.